# Yii2 : - Require one error message for three fields

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-validation

I have three dropdowns for  day, month, and year. when I applied required condition yii2 validation show individual error for all three fields. But I want single error message for three fields like "dob is required".

view file :

```
<?= $form->field($model, "month")->dropDownList([], ['class'=>'form-control day'])->label(false);?>
<?= $form->field($model, "day")->dropDownList([], ['class'=>'form-control day'])->label(false);?>
<?= $form->field($model, "year")->dropDownList([], ['class'=>'form-control year'])->label(false);?>
```

model :

```
public $day;    
public $month;
public $year;

[['month','day','year'], 'required', 'when' => function ($model) {
    return (($model->month == "") || ($model->day == "") || ($model->year == ""));
    }, 
    'whenClient' => "function (attribute, value) {
    return ($('#user-month').val() == '' || $('#user-day').val() == '' || $('#user-year').val() == '');
    }",'on'=>'profile'
]
```

This code showing me error messages for all three dropdowns individually. But i want single error message for dob: like "dob is required".

Comment: show your code of **model** and **view**

Comment: I have updated my question please check

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

Write this code in your **Model** :

```
public function rules()
 {
     return [
         [['month','day','year',],'required','on'=>['create','update'],'message' => 'Please enter DOB.'],
       ];
 }
```

Write this code in your **Action** in **Controller** where you call your **view**:

```
 $model = new YourModelName();
 $model->scenario = "create";
```

**Example** :

```
 $model = new User();
 $model->scenario = "create";
```

Comment: Seems like she has already used 'scenario=profile'. Your answer will give validation error for all three fields differently, for ex - Please enter DOB, Please enter DOB, Please enter DOB. She wants only one validation error for all three at once, for ex- Please enter DOB

Answer (score 0):

Maybe You sholud do something more like:

```
['month', 'validationFunction', 'skipOnEmpty' => false]
...
public function validationFunction($attribute, $params) {
    if( !$this->hasErrors() ) {
        if (!$this->month || !$this->day || !$this->year) {
            $this->addError($attribute, 'dob is required');
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: I improved answear, it must works in this way. Next time write something more than "not working".